# Codeigniter login problema vuelve atras en el navegador

Tags: codeigniter

tengo el siguiente inconveniente estoy usando codeigniter y cuando me logueo entra a la vista principal todo bien, pero cuando cierro sesión y cuando estoy devuelta en la vista vlogin "la de acceso al sistema " si presiono atrás en el navegador me devuelve a la vista  vrpincipal sin estar logueado. he revisado por la web pero no consigo una solución clara al problema. Adjunto controlador y vista con el metodo logout que es el que uso para destruir sesion. Desde ya muchas gracias..
// controlador clogin

```
<?php
```

/**
 *
 */
class Clogin extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('mlogin');

}

public function index() {

    $this->load->view('layout/header');
    //$this->load->view('layout/footer');
    $this->load->view('persona/vlogin');

}

public function ingresar() {

    //$this->load->library('encryption');
    $user = $this->input->post('username');
    $pass = md5($this->input->post('password'));

    $r = $this->mlogin->ingresar($user, $pass);

    if ($r == 1) {

        redirect('cprincipal');

    } else {

        redirect('clogin');

    }
}

public function logout() {

    if ($this->session->set_userdata('username')) {
        $this->session->sess_destroy('username');
        //redirect(base_url() . 'clogin');
        redirect('clogin');
    } else {
        redirect('clogin');
    }

}
```

}

//modelo mlogin

```
<?php
```

/**
 *
 */
class Mlogin extends CI_Model {

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

}

public function ingresar($user, $pass) {

    $this->db->select('usuarios.Id_usuario, usuarios.user, usuarios.password, usuarios.rol, usuarios.id_area, areas.area, areas.id_area');
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    //$this->db->from('areas');
    $this->db->where('user', $user);
    $this->db->where('password', $pass);
    $this->db->join('areas', 'areas.id_area = usuarios.id_area');

    $resultado = $this->db->get();

    if ($resultado->num_rows() == 1) {
        $r = $resultado->row();

        $s_usuario = array(
            's_Id_usuario' => $r->Id_usuario,
            's_user' => $r->user,
            's_rol' => $r->rol,
            's_area' => $r->area,
            's_id_area' => $r->id_area,
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($s_usuario);

        return 1;

    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

// vista vlogin

```
     <body>

    <section class="login-content">
      <div class="logo" style=" font-family: sans-serif; ">
        <h2 style="position: relative;z-index: 100 "> </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="login-box">
        <form class="login-form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>clogin/ingresar" method="POST">
          <h3 class="login-head"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-user"></i>ACCESO</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Usuario</label>
            <input class="form-control"  name="username"   type="text" autofocus title="Es obligatorio que ingreses usuario" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Contraseña</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password"  name="password" title="Es obligatorio que ingreses contraseña" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            </div>
          <div class="form-group btn-container">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Ingresar</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas controlar en tu **cprincipal** *(Intuyo que controlador principal)* que cualquier persona que vaya a acceder al metodo `Index` de dicho controlador este logueada.

```
    class CPrincipal extends CI_Controller
    {

        public function __construct()
        {

            parent::__construct();

            // User Access Control
            if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
                redirect('clogin');
            }
        }
    }
```

De esta forma al volver atrás o intentar acceder de cualquier forma a tu vista Principal a traves de una llamada a tu `CPrincipal` el constructor del mismo comprobará si existe la session. En caso contrario mandará al usuario de vuelta al *login*.

Te recomiendo usar arrays associativos multidimensionales para las variables de session.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $s_usuario);
```

De esta forma podrás enviar el array completo o hacer un unset de todos sus indices.

**Para cerrar la session correctamente...**

```
public function logout() {

    $this->load->library('session');

    $this->session->unset('logged_in'); // O clave de tu array.
    session_destroy();

    redirect('login', 'refresh');

}
```

Comment: Hola, no me funciona me deja conectarme me logueo y me vuelve a la vista vprincipal si doy atras en el navegador Cambie la linea en el modelo con $this->session y agrege la condicion como describes

Comment: Login => Vista Principal => Logout ... Ya aunque pulsas atras no te dejará ver la vista principal. Para ello debes de eliminar correctamente la session. Usa en tu funcion de Logout a la que debes de llamar al desloguear... $this->session->unset('logged_in); session_destroy(); redirect('login');

Comment: Eliminas las variables de sesion... destruyes la sesion y rediriges al login. Ahora si pulsas atras... la sesion esta cerrada no puedes entrar...

Comment: me da este error Call to undefined method CI_Session::unset() cuando me deslogueo en el metodo logout. Cambie el codigo en el metodo logout como describes y puse las tres líneas de código

Comment: Añade esta linea al principio del metodo logout(Esta editado arriba). O usa el archivo autoload.php para cargar automaticamente la libreria de sessiones en todo el proyecto.    this->load->library('session');

Comment: No me da el mismo error  Call to undefined method CI_Session::unset() agrege la libreria y ademas ya estaba en configurada en autoload